# How to get the highlighted row data from multiple Excel with pyhton

Tags: python, excel

I am new with python,but I would like to get the highlighted row data(with red color) from multiple Excel(xlsx).
And ideally extract the specific data to text.
I tried to write the code but it didn't work properly.

If there's a way to sort this out,I would be appriciated.

### Here's what I wrote.

```
import pathlib
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

f = open('dataresult.txt', 'w')
path = pathlib.Path(r"..\data")

for path_obj in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_obj)
    sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheetname]

        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            if sheet["A" + str(row)].fill == PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor="ff0000"):      
                f.write(sheet["O" + str(row)].value + ",")
                f.write(sheet["D" + str(row)].value)
                f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fill.startcolor.index to get the color in Hex format and then check the color is RED before writing to the text file. Note that you mentioned the output file should be dataresult.txt, so had to change the code as text files do not have sheets, etc. The output of the color will have FF at the start, so red would be FF followed by FF0000 in Hex. the cell.value will give the text in that particular cell. I have kept as much of your code as-is with minimal changes to enable you to achieve what you want.

```
import pathlib
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

f = open('dataresult.txt', 'w') ## You mentioned .txt format, so assuming NOT writing to excel
path = pathlib.Path(r"..\data")

for path_obj in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_obj)
    sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheetname]
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            if sheet["A" + str(row)].fill.start_color.index == 'FFFF0000': ## Get color - comes in Hex format with FF at start
## Removed as you are writing to .TXT, not excel
#                f.write(sheet["O" + str(row)].value + ",")
#                f.write(sheet["D" + str(row)].value)
#                f.write("\n")
                f.write(str(sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value)+"\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried the code that you've changed some, but unfortunately it shows nothing in .txt format.
Is there other line code that I might have to change?

Comment: I can think of only a couple of reasons. Please check that the open and close of the file is not missing or inside any loop. Also, are you checking under the correct directory? The dataresult.txt will be created in the same dir where your program will be running, not under data. Also, assuming there are excel (.xlsx) files in data folder and they have some cells with RED background in column-A.  I am seeing the file created and the text being written to it

Comment: If the `dataresult.txt` is not even created, try running just the file open and close. It would mean that those lines are not running. If a blank file is created, it would mean that `f.write()` never ran, which would indicate that there were no files with RED background in column A

Comment: I comfirmed everything that you mentioned and it seems nothing wrong. 
Therefore, I tried the code to other file which also includes multiple excel(.xlsx) and some cells with RED badkground and it worked for only one excel.
I suppose the loop code isn't working correctly.
Do you have any other idea to read multiple excel in the file..?

Comment: Sorry @jane - I did not change your code and searching through each file is part of that code. Also, it ran and picked up all xlsx files correctly when I ran it here. Was your code working (picking up multiple files) correctly earlier? Simple check could be to add print statements inside each of the for/if to see which part of code is behaving correctly

Comment: I tried it again and it worked perfectlly. Many thanks!!
Actually, I've got one more question for you if you're ok.. How can I extract each file name (which has some cells with RED background) to .txt format?

Comment: Hi @jane - glad to hear that worked... Regarding filename - you will have that name (full name including folder structure) of the file in the `path_obj` variable. While inside the loop, try printing it just before the `f.write()` OR you can add it in the f.write() itself, so that the file name is added to your .txt file

Comment: Understand. I will try it. Thank you so much for your support!!